# CSS rule for tablets and mobiles only, and not desktop?

Tags: css, responsive

How to make a CSS rule that only applies to tablets and mobiles (not desktop)?
If I use:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1400px)
```

"screen" means "browser window", but not "device screen". So this CSS rule will be applied if I shrink my browser window on desktop.

I saw *@media handheld* was deprecated.

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 1400px)
```

works fine, but *device-width* also seems to be deprecated, according to : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Comment: You should use `max-width`. The width of the viewport is the major factor that would require a layout change.

Comment: CSS rules based on *min-width* or *max-width* will be applied when the user shrinks its browser's window. I'm searching for CSS rules that are only applied to non-resizable browsers (tablets and smartphones). For example, if I write a rule to zoom fonts on small devices, I don't want this rule to be applied when the user shrinks its browser's window on its desktop.

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* 
  ##Device = Desktops
  ##Screen = 1281px to higher resolution desktops
*/

@media (min-width: 1281px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Laptops, Desktops
  ##Screen = B/w 1025px to 1280px
*/

@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1280px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Tablets, Ipads (landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 768px to 1024px
*/

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) and (orientation: landscape) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Low Resolution Tablets, Mobiles (Landscape)
  ##Screen = B/w 481px to 767px
*/

@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 767px) {

  //CSS

}

/* 
  ##Device = Most of the Smartphones Mobiles (Portrait)
  ##Screen = B/w 320px to 479px
*/

@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {

  //CSS

}
```

https://gist.github.com/gokulkrishh/242e68d1ee94ad05f488